# JSON files into HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to display a table based on JSON data.
My JSON is formatted like this as spellData.json in my local directory:

```
[["Flash", 22722], ["Ignite", 5126], ["Heal", 4666], ["Smite", 3970], ["Teleport", 3892], ["Exhaust", 3118], ["Mark", 2495], ["Ghost", 571], ["Barrier", 459], ["Clarity", 239], ["Cleanse", 132], ["Clairvoyance", 10]]
```

I need to iterate through this data, and create a table that looks something like:

Spell : Occurrences

So far, index.html looks like this:

```
        <html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $.getJSON('spellData.json', function(data) {
                var tr;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    tr = $('<tr/>');
                    tr.append("<td>" + data[i][0] + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + data[i][1] + "</td>");
                    $('table').append(tr);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th> Spell </th>
            <th> Occurences </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

On my side, only "Spell Occurrences" show up, and not the json data.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

UPDATE:
It seems like the code seems to work on other people's end.. But when I open index.html with a chrome, I only get "Spell Occurrences" and not the json data.

UPDATE:
It seems like the problem was that Chrome doesn't support cross origin requests, so I can't do .getJSON with local files.

Comment: works fine on my end... are you sure the `spellData.json` is in the correct directory?

Comment: Yes, it is in the same local directory as my index.html. It is only showing "Spell Occurrences" but not the json data

Comment: Tried moving `script` block containing `$.getJSON` to after `</table>` , before `</body>` ?

Comment: When do you get when you `console.log(data)` at the beginning of the `$.getJSON` block?

Comment: @guest271314 Just tried it, but json data still don't show up.

Comment: Tried full path to `spellData.json` ? e.g., "http: //full/path/to/spellData.json" ? Is protocol  `file:` ?

Comment: "UPDATE: It seems like the problem was that Chrome doesn't support cross origin requests, so I can't do .getJSON with local files." > @byInduction try the local web server in my answer to see if it works (it's CORS-enabled by default!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`js` at Question appear to return expected results ?

```js
var data = [
  ["Flash", 22722],
  ["Ignite", 5126],
  ["Heal", 4666],
  ["Smite", 3970],
  ["Teleport", 3892],
  ["Exhaust", 3118],
  ["Mark", 2495],
  ["Ghost", 571],
  ["Barrier", 459],
  ["Clarity", 239],
  ["Cleanse", 132],
  ["Clairvoyance", 10]
];

var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  tr = $('<tr/>');
  tr.append("<td>" + data[i][0] + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + data[i][1] + "</td>");
  $('table').append(tr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Spell</th>
      <th>Occurences</th>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: League of legends rulez! Your answer helped me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Ensure `spellData.json` is in the same directory as `index.html`
- consider using a simple web server to serve your files (https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server)
- and add promise chains so you can see any errors:

  ```
  $(function() {
      $.getJSON('spellData.json')
       .success(function(data) {
          var tr;
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              tr = $('<tr/>');
              tr.append("<td>" + data[i][0] + "</td>");
              tr.append("<td>" + data[i][1] + "</td>");
              $('table').append(tr);
          }
      })
      .error(function(e) { console.error(e); })
  });
  ```